# Is there a way to combine formatted output and full command arguments in one ps command?

Tags: solaris

In solaris, `/usr/ucb/ps auxww` gives full commandline arguments (without truncating long commands+arguments).

And `ps` has -o option that provides formatted output.

Is there a single command (or one-liner) that has both capabilities?

Note: the issue also has to do with `ps` truncating arguments after a specific width hence the need for `/usr/ucb/ps`.

Comment: Not sure about solaris, but in my experience lots of ps's truncate **if stdout is a tty**. Try piping the output like `ps whatever |cat`.

Comment: That doesn't work. Tested it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not with a single command that I'm aware of.

Solaris `ps` gets process data for such things as command-line arguments from the [`/proc/[PID]/psinfo` file](http://illumos.org/man/4/proc), which contains data that fills a `struct psinfo` per [`/usr/include/sys/procfs.h`](http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/uts/common/sys/procfs.h#273):

```
#define PRARGSZ     80  /* number of chars of arguments */
typedef struct psinfo {
    int pr_flag;    /* process flags (DEPRECATED; do not use) */
    int pr_nlwp;    /* number of active lwps in the process */
    .
    .
    .
    char    pr_fname[PRFNSZ];   /* name of execed file */
    char    pr_psargs[PRARGSZ]; /* initial characters of arg list */
...
```

So you can't get the entire set of command line arguments from `/usr/bin/ps`.  You could use `/usr/ucb/ps ...` as you've already noted and format your output using `awk` or similar.  There's also `pargs`, which can be used to emit command-line arguments.  (The installed location of `pargs` varies depending on Solaris version.)

Be aware, though, that a process can modify its arguments, and to get the full argument information requires permission to read the process address space.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `ps -eo args`  if you want to see the every arguments

Anyway you can combine the first example with more options

```
ps -eo user,pid,args
```

Comment: ps truncates args after a specific width, and hence unable to display full command line arguments in all cases.

Comment: I don't have this problem in linux.

Comment: @c4f4t0r This isn't Linux.

Comment: @AndrewHenle yes I know, I wrote that to say, that is a solaris problem.